# Using CloudFlare with CloudWays Digital Ocean PHP Stack

Tags: dns, cdn, cloudflare, cname, cloudways

We are hosting our website on CloudWays Digital Ocean server, and our application is a PHP Stack.

That means the domain name isn't using ns1 ns2 as usual, but is using CNAME record to point to the PHP stack.

We need to start using CloudFlare CDN with our website, and I already know CloudFlare is implemented by changing the nameservers ns1 and ns2 to their nameservers.

But we're not using nameservers on our domain.

So, how do we start using CloudFlare, how do we set it up so it starts receiving traffic from the domain that points to our PHP Stack with a CNAME record?

Answer (score 0):

Your domain will always have a nameserver option. Once you point your DNS to CloudFlare by changing your nameservers, you can then from CloudFlare point your CNAME records through CloudFlare to your Digital Ocean server.

If you are asking how to set-up CloudFlare without changing nameservers via a CNAME set-up, you either need to be an enterprise customer or need a company who is a CloudFlare Partner to set this up for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question needs to be updated. Now, Cloudways offer a Cloudflare Enterprise plan for their customers (integration with a few clicks) and when it comes to a free Cloudflare plan then read this guide: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/wordpress-cloudflare-cdn/